# Entity Framework changes are not reflected in SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I’m new to the Entity Framework and I have a little problem and I just can’t find the solution. I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express, VS2012, AdventureWorks 2012 and it’s a WPF App.

The only thing I want to do is modify a cell and see the modification in the DB with the Management Studio.

I went through a lot of questions here and googled it (everyone refers to Copy to Output Directory Option) but I still seem not to get it right.

What I did is the following:

```
private AW_Entities context;
private List<Address> adresses;

context = new AW_Entities();
adresses = context.Addresses.OrderBy(x => x.City).ToList();

var currentAdress = context.Addresses.Find(1000);
currentAdress.City = currentAdress.City + " xxxx";

context.SaveChanges();
```

My WPF App displays it and shows no errors my db doesn't reflect any changes.

My "Copy to Output Directory Option" is set to "Do not copy"

My connection string is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AW_Entities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AdventureWorks2012;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set the entity status to "Modified":

```
context.Entry(adresses).State = EntityState.Modified;
```